# Looking for an algebraic number with a balanced sequence of digits

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

It is generally believed that all irrational algebraic numbers $\alpha$  are [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), in all bases. In base $2$ that implies that there are arbitrary large $n$ such that for the binary expansion

$$\alpha = \ldots .a_1a_2a_2 \ldots a_{2n}\ldots$$

there are equal numbers of $0$, and $1$ in the sequence $(a_1, \ldots, a_{2n})$.

Indeed, if instead of $0$, $1$, we have $-1$, $1$, then we get a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) on the line and it will return to the origin infinitely often.

---

[image: root 2, 1 million digits]

I considered $1$ million binary digits of $\sqrt{2}$ after the dot, converted $0$ to $-1$, and took the partial sums, then ploted them on the vertical

---

[image: root 3, 1 million binary digits]

Same thing, but for $\sqrt{3}$.

---

[image: root 6, 1 million binary digits]

Same thing, but for $\sqrt{6}$. There seems to be an excess of $1$'s over $0$' that will never be corrected. However:

---

[image: root 6, 5 million binary digits]

Same thing for $\sqrt{6}$, $5$ million digits. There are corrections, and again we are hitting even

---

The above seems to be related to [large deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory).

However, I would like to see examples  in larger bases $b$ ($3$, $4$, $\ldots$) where there would be an equal amount of digits $k$, $0\le k\le b-1$, in the chunk $a_1\ldots a_{bn}$. That I could not find, just by searching ternary expansions of some radicals.  It does not mean that they should not exist, but perhaps the theory of probability says that it is improbable to happen. Still, I wonder if anybody has some concrete examples of algebraic numbers with large "balanced chunks"  ( in base $10$ that looks quite improbable...)

Thank you for your interest. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Notes:

1. @Greg Martin rightly pointed out that, since the algebraic numbers ( even quadratic numbers) are dense, there will be example of them with arbitrary initial chunks.  Sill,  if somebody says: take this fairly simple algebraic number ( small definition), and check that in the first 3 million ternary digits there are equal numbers of $0$, $1$, $2$, that would be a pleasant surprise. If another simple example of a number would have equal number of $0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $9$'s in the first $1$ billion decimal digits, surely that would be impressive.
   ( to quantify simple, the sum of absolute values of the coefficients of the defining equation is small).
2. @Dave L. Renfro correctly pointed out that normal numbers have a clear definition that does not imply "random" binary digits.  However, lots of people believe that irrational algebraic do have random digits, whatever random may mean. So that would settle the binary expansion of algebraic irrational, modulo some (unattainable) proofs.

Comment: The algebraic irrationals are dense in $\Bbb R$, so you can find an algebraic irrational (of prescribed degree even, if you want) with any string of initial digits that you like.

Comment: Your 2nd sentence is not true -- normality does NOT imply there be **equal** numbers of digits in the way you described. The limiting frequencies will be equal (each to $\frac{1}{2}),$ but the limit of a sequence does not have to be one of the terms of the sequence (much less be an arbitrarily large term of the sequence, i.e. infinitely many terms of the sequence).

Comment: This might be a silly question, but is it in any way easy to prove that the number formed by reading the binary representation of, say, $\sqrt{2}$ as a decimal is not algebraic?

Comment: @Chris Lewis: I don't think one can prove even that, and we believe $\sqrt{2}$ normal in base $10$.

Comment: @orangeskid I hope I was clear - I wondered if we could prove that the decimal number $1.0110101\ldots$ (which has the same digits as the binary representation of $\sqrt2$) was transcendental. If it were algebraic, it would obviously be a counterexample to the statement all irrational algebraic numbers are normal, so I assume that either means 1) it's transcendental and we can prove that it is or 2) it's suspected transcendental but beyond our scope to prove. It seems counterintuitive that a number generated this way would be transcendental, but my intuition around normal numbers is not great!

Comment: @Chris Lewis: 2) would be my guess, yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation

$$
9091x+x^n=114
$$

has a solution close to

$$
\frac{114}{9091}=0.\overline{0125398746}
$$

that gets closer as $n$ increases, so you can get algebraic numbers with arbitarily long balanced digit sequences, all with the same moderately sized coefficients.

Similar equations for bases $2$ to $9$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
11_2x + x^n&=&1_2\\
222_3x + x^n&=&12_3\\
101_4x + x^n&=&2_4\\
1032_5x + x^n&=&14_5\\
51_6x + x^n&=&2_6\\
36412_7x + x^n&=&524_7\\
335_8x + x^n&=&5_8\\
608_9x + x^n&=&25_9\\
\end{eqnarray*}

[Here’s the Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4840081.java) I used to find these.

Perhaps $51_6x + x^n=2_6$ is the one that’s most in the spirit of your question; in base $10$ it’s

$$
31x+x^n=2
$$

with coefficients that could reasonably be called “small”. The solutions are near $\frac2{31}$, which is $0.\overline{021534}_6$.

Comment: Nice!  Even if $n$ should have also been under control, this is clever!

Comment: Getting a small rational with a balanced sequence of digits is a feat in itself!  (Cannot see the code on github). By any chance, approximately how many chunks of $10$'s do you get for a large $n$?  ( a linear amount?)

Comment: Yes, the number of balanced digits is linear in $n$. The solution of $qx+x^n=p$ is very well approximated by $x=\frac pq-\frac1q\left(\frac pq\right)^n$, so you get a factor $\frac pq$ closer when you increment $n$. For instance, for $\frac pq=\frac{114}{9091}\approx0.01$ that's almost $2$ digits.